# Best way to send Personalized emails to my registered users?

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, mailchimp

My users register on my website (200 per day) and can select from a large pool of categories (100) of content they are interested in: Tech, Business, Health... and so on.

I want to send them an email every week with a digest of the categories they selected.

What's the best tool for the job?

I'm not sure you can do that with Mailchimp and is really expensive considering my user count growth. Plus, users would register on my database and then would have to re register and confirm it on Mailchimp.

I was thinking of making my own / buying something custom that uses Amazon SES.. Looks cheaper. Is that a good idea? What would the obstacles be? Is it very hard to manage bounces, getting your domain through spam blockers and stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mailchimp is a great way to go here.  You can use their API so that your users do not need to `re-register.`  Their content creation tools are great as well so you can build everything you need with them.  https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/gettingstarted/connectivity.php

Building out your own tools really depends on what all your platform does today.. that make vs buy decision is a complex one.

Comment: I've been reading it and it seems I would have to use Mandrill to send specific emails to specific users.

Comment: Plus the cost of Mailchimp is huge

Comment: You can send emails to groups of people by data that you send to Mailchimp.  So you can sync your data to mailchimp then email off that data.  The cost being huge is hard to over come.  There are other options out ther like mailchimp but they are all going to be in the same price range or higher.  If cost is higher priority then features then you can use Mailgun or Mandrill to send your emails. More transactional pricing like AWS SES.